# Haskell Adding Elements to Tuples/Lists in order

Tags: list, haskell

I have defined a list of (String, Int) pairs.

```
 type PatientList = [(String,Int)]
```

I need to add data to this list in form 'name' and 'number', where number will increment for each addition to the list, for example the list (or tuple) after 3 name additions will look like:

```
 [("bob", 1), ("ted", 2), ("harry", 3)]
```

Name will be captured using the following code:

```
  do putStr "You are? "
  name <- getLine
```

My current solution is to create a list of names e.g. (bob, ted, harry) and then using zip, combine these lists as follows:

```
 zip = [1...]["bob","ted","harry"]
```

This solution doesn't fulfil my requirements as I wish to add to the list at different times and not combine together. How can I do this?

Comment: If efficiency isn't a concern (or the lists stay short), you can use `length patients` to find out what number comes next. If efficiency is a concern, use a different data structure which stores the size and has faster append/update.

Comment: Is there a good reason for including the numbers in the list? It looks like you could regenerate them any time they were needed by zipping with `[1..]`.

Comment: For example, if i remove an element from the list, that number cannot be used again on re-zipping.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but why do you need this? Are you trying to simulate a database or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it better to keep the list in reverse order?

```
[("harry", 3), ("ted", 2), ("bob", 1)]
```

Than adding will be in constant time:

```
add :: PatientList -> String -> PatientList
add [] newName = [newName]
add ((oldName, x):xs) newName = (newName, x+1):(oldName, x):xs
```

When you need whole list in order, you just in O(lenght yourList) linear time:

```
reverse patientList
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use an [`IntMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-IntMap-Lazy.html), from the `containers` package.

```
import Data.IntMap (IntMap)
import qualified Data.IntMap as IntMap

type PatientList = IntMap String

registerPatient :: PatientList -> String -> PatientList
registerPatient pList name
  | IntMap.null plist = IntMap.singleton 1 name  
  | otherwise         = let (n, _) = findMax pList 
                        in IntMap.insert (succ n) name plist
```

Answer (score 2):

As said before if speed isn't a concern use length

```
add :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
add name xs = xs ++ [(name, length xs)]
```

But if you remove an element this will mess up you id so maybe

```
add name xs = xs ++ [(name, 1 + ( snd (last xs) ) )]
```

I haven't tried running any of this because I'm not a computer with ghc, but you should get the idea.